# Weird issue on adding day to a date

Tags: php, date, time

I'm facing a weird problem about adding days to a date.

```
$date='2015-06-27';
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date. '+ 1 days'));
```

It should output 2015-06-28 , but it actually output 1970-01-01 .
The strange thing is that,it works if i'm writing it like this:

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2015-06-27 + 1 days'));
```

**UPDATE:**  The $date is taken from database,like this:

```
$arr = explode(" ", $row_cal['StartTime'], 2);
$date= $arr[0];
```

On output it shows what it suppose to show.I dont know if is something wrong with this.$row_cal['StartTime'] is 2015-06-27 00:00:00

Comment: Well, what does `$date. '+ 1 days'` result in? Hint: no space before the `+`...

Comment: @deceze , i also trim() it ... doesn't work

Comment: @deceze The `space` causing the problem.

Comment: @Ja͢ck , then what is the problem? i can't figure out...

Comment: @PetruLebada It means that, most likely, you're not showing us something; surely, that code [in isolation](http://3v4l.org/HuAEJ) gives you the correct results, am I wrong?

Comment: @Ja͢ck , i have nothing else to show you,that's all...what you mean by isolation ? if you mean local it doesn't

Comment: Hang on, which version of PHP are you running?

Comment: What I mean by "in isolation" is [this 3v4l result page](http://3v4l.org/HuAEJ).

Comment: @Ja͢ck, PHP Version 5.3.29

Answer (score 1):

Might be the `space` is the issue between the `date` and `+`.

```
$date = '2015-06-27';
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date. ' + 1 days'));
```

**Output**

```
2015-06-28
```

You can also try with -

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+ 1 days', strtotime($date)));
```

[Working Code](https://eval.in/386001)

**Update**

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+ 1 days', strtotime($row_cal['StartTime'])));
```

No need of `explode` for that format. PHP will take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestion from b0s3 you can use the `\DateTime` class if you're on PHP > 5.2

```
$date = new \DateTime('2015-06-27');
$date->modify('+1 days');
```

where

```
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

gives you `2015-06-28` which I think is your desired result.

Comment: While this is good advice, it doesn't explain why OP's code "doesn't work".

Comment: @Jack I foolishly didn't try OPs answer and just assumed it was unsupported syntax. Now they have edited their question...